# How to fix this two page overlaping?

Tags: html

How can i fix this issue? Everything is ok in desktop version but in mobile version pages overlap. Dont know what to do :D
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBQon.jpg)

Code:

Comment: umm.... Code???

Comment: I am new to this platform. I wanted to put my code but i got an error message that its too long

Comment: That's because you need to show only a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Please see the [help] for more information about how to format this question

Answer (score 0):

Appreciated if you show us a little of your code to know your scenario. Anyways I think I have got what you need.

Use containers relative positioned inside an absolute container. Give them a width. Make them float left.
Use @media tags to resize them when you desire to change.

It is the right way to work. First you define for small devices then resize if larger. And you use relative positioning when you desire wrap normal (not flex) boxes.

I give you an example. I begin giving 100% width for small devices and I resize to 50% for larger screens (In the example im doing the change at 500px but you can use other). Give a look. Run the snippet on fullscreen to see the change and resize your browser screen to the minimum. Or copy paste the code and try it.

Your containers appearently seems absolute positioned.

```css
.absolute {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.one {
display:block;
float:left;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:#f1f0f1;
}
.two {
display:block;
float:left;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:#a0aca0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:500px) {
.one, .two {
width:50%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
  <div class="one"> PEACE </div>
  <div class="two"> IN THE WORLD </div>
</div>
```